# Bad operands for Strings

Tags: java

Sorry for this question, but I just can not find the answer to this problem! The array is declared as a string just so you know. 
This is the code:

```
public static void bubblesort()
 {
     int outer,inner;
     for(outer=nElems-1; outer>0; outer--)
     {
         for(inner=0;inner<outer;inner++)
         {
             if(array[inner] > array[inner+1]){ <<The problem is here.
                 swap(inner,inner+1);
             }
         }
     }

 }
```

Comment: What is the question?? And full code plz..

Comment: How can a string be bigger than a string?

Comment: What is the problem? Stack trace?

Comment: You cannot compare Strings with `>` or `<` operators. Take a look at `String#compareTo()` method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `>` or `<` on `String`s. Try `compareTo`:

```
if (array[inner].compareTo(array[inner+1]) > 0) {
```

[Here are the docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo%28T%29) for the `Comparable` interface, which `String` implements.

Comment: Will this compare and then see if the difference is bigger than 0 and then swap them?

Comment: Thanks, I should know the answer to this, but I could not figure it out for the life of me. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use arithmethic operators for `String` type such

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you can't compare two strings in java like this:

```
array[inner] > array[inner+1]
```

You can concatenate two `String` objects with `+` but this overloading does not stand for `>` or `<` for that matter.

If you want to compare two `String`s use the `compareTo` method of a `Comparator<String>`.